# Keyboard shortcut to access Gnome Panel like Unity

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-panel

In Unity the sortcut `Alt + F10` allows to access the Unity Menu, including AppMenu and AppIndicators. Does Gnome Shell have a similar shortcut to manage the panel with the keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Typically this is done by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and navigating to Panel or Top Bar. Then use your arrow keys and Enter/Return to launch. There may be more keyboard controls for the top bar but I'm not aware of them, maybe someone else will be.

Under 3.8 and *possibly* 3.6 there are additional helpful shell shortcuts in:

Settings(gnome-control-enter)> Keyboard> Shortcuts> System

For instance I set "Open application menu" to use the xf86menu key, so whenever I hit the Menu key, it open the appmenu. Note some things like ctrl+alt+tab can't be changed there, but an extension could probably provide this ability.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

In my 12.04, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> for the lower panel, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> for the upper one.